# Authenticate extends Middleware redirect me if i have permission

Tags: laravel, middleware

Hello please can explain me why it happedned . i hve make middleware and was work ok but suddenly stop and redirect me any way problem in method where Authenticate .php

```
 class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {

        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

this return me to login if i logged not allow for user he have permisson to go this
middleware

```
class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()){
            if (Auth::user()->user_type == 1){  //Any Manger Can Access only Not Users
                return $next($request);
            }else{
              return redirect()->back();
//            abort(403);
            }
        }else{
            return redirect()->back();
        }

    }

}
```

and user_type == 1 was try in middle ware dd(Auth::user()); but if put it in side method redirectTo

dd(Auth::user());
return info bout user but not return nothing direct go to login in Authenticate ,

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function () {

Route::get('admin/dashboard', function () {
    return view('admin.index');
})->name('admin.dashboard');
```

and befor it was work ok . what problem !

Comment: can you explain that in a different way, i am having a hard time following what you are trying to describe

Comment: in user table i have column called user_type and give 1 and make middleware and  public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()){
            if (Auth::user()->user_type !== 0){  //Any Manger Can Access only Not Users
                return $next($request);
            }else{
              return redirect()->back();
//            abort(403);
            }
        }else{
            return redirect()->back();
        }    to access admin route and make group route protected with middleware but  method    protected function redirectTo($request)

Comment: what about this isn't working?

Comment: method  protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
} return me back direct not go to middleware because try dd(Auth::User()) in middleware not back anyhthing

Comment: what about that method? it is never being called

Comment: in side Authenticate .php

   protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}

Comment: what middleware is this `handle` method for that you are showing us?

Comment: what middleware is this handle method ! what problem with this ? it was work but after i make cache:clear everything stop

Comment: what middleware are you showing in your code, what is this `handle` method for? ... i can't make sense of what you are showing or saying at all

Comment: handle  this method in adminMiddleware check if user have permission admin or not if user_type == 1 or 2 or 3 so can throw if ==0 so it user . cant access this route

Comment: the route you are showing has the `auth` middleware applied, where are you applying this `adminMiddleware` to that route?

Comment: edit post , not make any sense and i try dd(Auth::user()); inside handler not back anything .